# Minmax algorithm chooses the worst move for some depths

Tags: c, artificial-intelligence, minmax

I have to code a player for the FloodWars, the game on Android. So far I succeeded in coding a minmax and a material evaluator, which is straightforward.

My problem is that on a specific table, on odd depths greater than 9, it gives the worst move. Here is the table:

```
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
@@**..**@@.#@@.##
```

The colors are replaced by: `'@', '#', '+', '.', '*'`. Here is the output on specified depths:

```
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
++**..**@@.#@@.##
```

On all depths smaller than 11 it gives the expected output:

```
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
****..**@@.#@@.##
```

Here is some pieces of the code, the important ones:

```
int minmaxMin(int lvl, board *b)
{
    if(lvl == 0)
    {
        return evalM(b, g_me, g_he);
    }
    board cpB;
    moves M = getMoves(b, g_me, g_he);
    int score = 1000000;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
    {
        copyBoard(b, &cpB);
        memset(was, 0, MAX_L * MAX_C);
        floodfill_ch(&cpB, g_he.l, g_he.c, b->d[g_he.l][g_he.c], M.m[i]);

        score = min(score, minmaxMax(lvl - 1, &cpB)); 
    }

    return score;
}

int minmaxMax(int lvl, board *b)
{
    if(lvl == 0)
    {
        return evalM(b, g_me, g_he);
    }
    board cpB;
    moves M = getMoves(b, g_me, g_he);
    int score = -1000000;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
    {
        copyBoard(b, &cpB);
        memset(was, 0, MAX_L * MAX_C);
        floodfill_ch(&cpB, g_me.l, g_me.c, b->d[g_me.l][g_me.c], M.m[i]);

        score = max(score, minmaxMin(lvl - 1, &cpB)); 
    }

    return score;
}
```

- lvl is depth, and board is the board stored as d[MAX_L][MAX_C] - data and l(number of rows), c(number of columns) - the actual size of the board.
- Function floodfill_ch(...) changes on a the board a group of a color into another color, getMoves(...) gets the legal moves(all moves - corners) and evalM(...) gets the material score of a board(squares dominated by 'me' - squares dominate by 'he').
- g_me and g_he are the position of the players(row and column).

I swapped the arguments of the `evalM`, how @WeatherVane suggested, but nothing had happened at all. I printed on stdout the result of the child of the root and the result(scores) were different, but the program chose the worst one.
Here is the debug screen for program with arguments swapped:

```
scr: 0:
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##

scr: 0:
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##

scr: -26:
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
```

And this is the output without arguments being swapped:

```
scr: 39:
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##
    ++**..**@@.#@@.##

scr: 26:
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##
    ..**..**@@.#@@.##

scr: 39:
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
    ****..**@@.#@@.##
```

The score is the score marked on the children of the root.

Here is the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define DEBUG

#ifndef DEBUG
  #define fin stdin
  #define fout stdout
#else
  FILE *fin, *fout, *tty;
#endif

#define MAX_L 50
#define MAX_C 50

typedef struct
{
  char d[MAX_L][MAX_C];
  int l, c;
}board;

typedef struct
{
  int l, c;
}player;

typedef struct
{
  char m[3];
}moves;

int max(int a, int b)
{
  return a > b ? a : b;
}

int min(int a, int b)
{
  return a < b ? a : b;
}


//utilities
void readBoard(FILE *fin, board *b, player* me, player* he);
void printBoard(FILE *fout, board *b);

//eval
int evalM(board* b, player me, player he);

//search
int minmaxMin(int lvl, board *b);
int minmaxMax(int lvl, board *b);
int negamax(int lvl, board *b, char col);


int alphabetaMin(int lvl, board *bo, int a, int b);
int alphabetaMax(int lvl, board *bo, int a, int b);

void floodfill_ch(board *b, int l, int c, char from, char to);


player g_me, g_he;
char was[MAX_L][MAX_C];

//moves
moves getMoves(board *b, player me, player he)
{
  char pM [] = {'@', '#', '+', '.', '*'};
  moves M;
  int i, j = 0;

  //printf("inside getMoves (%c, %c): ", b->d[me.l][me.c], b->d[he.l][he.c]);
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    if(pM[i] != b->d[me.l][me.c] && pM[i] != b->d[he.l][he.c])
      M.m[j++] = pM[i]/*, printf("'%c' ", pM[i])*/;
  //printf("\n");
  return M;
}

void copyBoard(board *src, board *dst)
{
  dst -> l = src -> l;
  dst -> c = src -> c;
  memcpy(dst -> d, src -> d, MAX_C * MAX_L);
}

int main()
{
  #ifdef DEBUG
  fin = fopen("in", "r");
  fout = fopen("out", "w");
  tty = fopen("debugyline", "w");
  #endif
  board currentState;
  board cpB;
  board winner;
  player me, he;
  int score;

  readBoard(fin, &currentState, &me, &he);
  g_me = me, g_he = he;
  printf("reported: (%d %d) (%d %d)\n", me.l, me.c, he.l, he.c);
  printf("reported score: %d\n", evalM(&currentState, me, he));
  printBoard(stdout, &currentState);

  moves M = getMoves(&currentState, g_me, g_he);
  printf("possible moves: '%c' '%c' '%c';\n", M.m[0], M.m[1], M.m[2]);
  score = -1000000;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    copyBoard(&currentState, &cpB);
    memset(was, 0, MAX_L * MAX_C);
    floodfill_ch(&cpB, g_me.l, g_me.c, cpB.d[g_me.l][g_me.c], M.m[i]);

    int x = minmaxMin(10, &cpB);
    #ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stdout, "    scr: %d:\n", x, evalM(&cpB, g_he, g_me));
    printBoard(stdout, &cpB);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\n\n\n\n");
    #endif

    if(x > score)
    {
      score = x;
      copyBoard(&cpB, &winner);
    }
  }

  printf("\n\n");
  printf("minimax scored at: %d\n", score);
  printBoard(stdout, &winner);


  #ifdef DEBUG
  fclose(fin);
  fclose(fout);
  fclose(tty);
  #endif
  return 0;
}
//search

//--
void floodfill_ch(board *b, int l, int c, char from, char to)
{
  if(l >= 0 && l < b->l && c >= 0 && c < b->c && !was[l][c] && b->d[l][c] == from)
  {
    b->d[l][c] = to;
    was[l][c] = 1;
    char ldir[] = {0,  0, -1, 1},
       cdir[] = {1, -1,  0, 0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      floodfill_ch(b, l + ldir[i], c + cdir[i], from, to);
  }
}
//--

//minmax (mm123)
int minmaxMin(int lvl, board *b)
{
  if(lvl == 0)
  {
    #ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(tty, "scr = %d: \n", evalM(b, g_he, g_me));
    //printBoard(tty, b);
    //fprintf(tty, "\n\n\n\n\n");
    #endif
    return evalM(b, g_he, g_me);
  }
  board cpB;
  moves M = getMoves(b, g_me, g_he);
  int score = 1000000;
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    copyBoard(b, &cpB);
    memset(was, 0, MAX_L * MAX_C);
    floodfill_ch(&cpB, g_he.l, g_he.c, b->d[g_he.l][g_he.c], M.m[i]);

    score = min(score, minmaxMax(lvl - 1, &cpB));
  }

  return score;
}

int minmaxMax(int lvl, board *b)
{
  if(lvl == 0)
  {
    #ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(tty, "scr = %d: \n", evalM(b, g_he, g_me));
    printBoard(tty, b);
    fprintf(tty, "\n\n\n\n\n");
    #endif
    return evalM(b, g_me, g_he);
  }
  board cpB;
  moves M = getMoves(b, g_me, g_he);
  int score = -1000000;

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    copyBoard(b, &cpB);
    memset(was, 0, MAX_L * MAX_C);
    floodfill_ch(&cpB, g_me.l, g_me.c, b->d[g_me.l][g_me.c], M.m[i]);
    /*
    #ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(tty, "%d:\n", lvl - 1);
    printBoard(tty, &cpB);
    fprintf(tty, "\n\n\n\n\n");
    #endif
    */
    score = max(score, minmaxMin(lvl - 1, &cpB));
  }

  return score;
}



// eval (ev456)
int sum;

void floodfill(board *b, int l, int c, char src)
{
  if(l >= 0 && l < b->l && c >= 0 && c < b->c && !was[l][c] && b->d[l][c] == src)
  {
    sum ++;
    was[l][c] = 1;
    char ldir[] = {0,  0, -1, 1},
       cdir[] = {1, -1,  0, 0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      floodfill(b, l + ldir[i], c + cdir[i], src);
  }
}

int evalM(board* b, player me, player he)
{
  int s_me, s_he;

  sum = 0;
  memset(was, 0, MAX_L * MAX_C);
  floodfill(b, me.l, me.c, b->d[me.l][me.c]);
  s_me = sum;

  sum = 0;
  memset(was, 0, MAX_L * MAX_C);
  floodfill(b, he.l, he.c, b->d[he.l][he.c]);
  s_he = sum;

  return s_me - s_he;
}

// I/O => board (iob1234)
void readBoard(FILE *fin, board *b, player* me, player* he)
{
    int l, c;
    char ch, t;
  player pJ, pS;
    t = fgetc(fin);
    fscanf(fin," ");

    ch = fgetc(fin);
    l = 0;
    while(ch != EOF && ch != '\n')
    {
        c = 0;
        while(ch != '\n' && ch != ' ' && ch != EOF)
        {
            b->d[l][c] = ch;
            ch = fgetc(fin);
            c++;
        }
        ch = fgetc(fin);
        l++;
    }

  b->l = l;
  b->c = c;

  pJ.l = l-1, pJ.c = 0;
  pS.l = 0, pS.c = c-1;

  if(t == 'J')
    *me = pJ, *he = pS;
  else if(t == 'S')
    *me = pS, *he = pJ;
  #ifdef DEBUG
  else printf("debug: (error) type of player broken; exiting...\n"), exit(-1);
  #endif
}

void printBoard(FILE *fout, board *b)
{
  int l, c;
  for(l = 0; l < b->l; l++)
  {
    fprintf(fout, "        ");
    for(c = 0; c < b->c; c++)
      fprintf(fout, "%c", b->d[l][c]);
    fprintf(fout, "\n");
  }
}
```

The call for minmax algorithm is `minmaxMin(10, &cpB);`

Comment: The two functions call each other recursively, as though you are projecting moves by each player forwards, and they differ in the me/he arguments for `floodfill`. Did you intend to swap the me/he arguments for `evalM` and `getMoves` in one of those `minmax...` functions too?

Comment: @WeatherVane It doesn't matter if i swap getMoves arguments, it's the same moves. I swaped the arguments in evalM, how you said, but is the same output.

Comment: Don't only show _some pieces of the code_ - show a complete program.